# How to render the header again in react navigation when user add something

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Here
Let me show you the photo.

[image: Photo]

What I want to do is I want to add number as badge beside the shopping cart.
But the problem is that the navigation component does not re-render even when I change the value from another component.

here the code for header navigator

```
const createMyStackNavigator = (name, screen, whatStack) => ({navigation}) => {
  whatStack = createStackNavigator();
  return (
    <whatStack.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        headerStyle: {backgroundColor: `${headerColor}`},
        headerTintColor: '#fff',
      }}>
      <whatStack.Screen
        name={name}
        component={screen}
        options={{
          title: name,
          headerLeft: () => (
            <Icon2.Button
              name="navicon"
              size={25}
              backgroundColor={headerColor}
              onPress={() => {
                navigation.openDrawer();
              }}></Icon2.Button>
          ),
          headerRight: () => (
            <Icon2.Button
              name="shopping-bag"
              size={25}
              backgroundColor={headerColor}
              onPress={() => {
                navigation.openDrawer();
              }}>
              <Text style={{color: 'white'}}>{productInCart}</Text>
            </Icon2.Button>
          ),
        }}
      />
    </whatStack.Navigator>
  );
};
```

Here is how it creating the navigator

```
const DrawerNavigator = ({navigation}) => {
    const isFocused = useIsFocused();

  const cartList = useSelector((state) => state.productReducer.cartList);
    productInCart = cartList.OrderDTO?.OrderLines.length

  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator drawerContent={(props) => <DrawerContent {...props} />}>
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="ProductScreen"
        component={ProductScreenStackScreen}
      />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
};
```

As you can see `{productinCart}` should be updated when its value is updated in other component.

But It's does not. Can you guys suggest some ideas? So that whenever user click certain button
The header will renader again

Comment: Are you averse to using redux to manage your state? Obviously you need to be mindful about component scope, and how local state is managed accordingly.